# Core Graphics vs WebView for PDF display in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, core-graphics

I am working on this project where I am required to display PDF files. I have two options to do this.

1. Using the UIWebView
2. Using Core Graphics

I've done some reading regarding both the approaches and found that both of them have their own advantages and disadvantages. For example,

1. UIWebview is slow and takes up a lot of memory because it loads the entire PDF at once but handles the pinch and Tap zoom.
2. Core Graphics gives low level controls but the onus of implementing zoom is on me.

I am downloading the PDF from a server in form of individual pages. So I dont stand the problem of using up too much memory. But I need to display thumbnails for which I'll have to use Quartz (Core Graphics). Would it be better if I combine the two i.e; webview for displaying PDF and Core Graphics for thumbnails?

I am not able to come to a conclusion as to which technology I want to go with considering the long run. Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: yes you can proceed with UIWebView for loading pdf and Quartz for thumbnails that would be a better option